# handling angle math in three.js

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, webgl

I'm drawing a bunch of arcs by making 102 lines (start point, endpoint, and 100 curve points)

the problem occurs when an arc has a start point that is greater in value than the end point. for example:

start point: 359
end point  : 88

in the following example, the arc should be in the empty area of the circle
http://jsfiddle.net/XsjgH/1/

I tried so many things. for example,

```
            function getARC(x, y, r, a){
    a = a * (Math.PI/180);
    var ax = +x + +r * Math.cos(+a),
        ay = +y + +r * Math.sin(+a),
        res = [];
        res['x'] = ax,
        res['y'] = ay;

    return res; 
}
function DRAWarc(cx, cy, ra, sa, ea){
        var arcFactor = 1;
            if(+sa > +ea){
                arcFactor = -1;
                var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xff00f0,
                });
            }else{
                var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0x0000ff,
                });
            }


            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

                var s = getARC(cx, cy, ra, sa);
                geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(s['x'], s['y'], 0));

                var step = (+ea - +sa)/100;
                var pass = 0;
                var reset = 0;
                for(var i=1;i<=100;i++){
                    if(+sa > +ea && ((+sa + (+step * +i))*arcFactor) < 360 && reset == 0){
                        pass = 1;
                    }
                    if(((+sa + (+step * +i))*arcFactor) < sa){
                        reset = 1;
                        pass = 0;
                    }
                    if(((+sa + (+step * +i))*arcFactor) < ea || pass == 1){
                        var t = getARC(cx, cy, ra, ((+sa + (+step * +i))*arcFactor));
                        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(t['x'], t['y'], 0));
                        //alert((+sa + (+step * +i)));
                    }
                }
                reset = 0;
                var f = getARC(cx, cy, ra, ea);
                geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(f['x'], f['y'], 0));

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            scene.add(line);

        }
```

Comment: whats the exact problem? please also post a jsfiddle if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think i figured it out.

I added this code to calculate the "step" in between points on the arc when its a problematic arc. basically it makes the start angle zero then calculates the step.

I think the problem was that i had a negative step.

```
              var step;
                    if(sa > ea){
                        var offset = 360 - sa;
                        step = (+ea + offset)/100;
                    } else {
                        step = (+ea - +sa)/100;
                    }
```

and heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/475Ga/

edit: the (sa > ea) was comparing the length of the string, so add a + before each variable to fix it.